# Special charecter ` in thymeleaf link

Tags: hyperlink, thymeleaf, special-characters

I am testing the special character in the link by downloading a file called `` !@#$%^&()_+=-{}[]'`~.doc ``. And I found that my page can show ` in th:text, but ` in th:href is autometically converted into %60.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-item-action" th:each="file: ${filesList}">
            <a th:href="${'http://localhost:8080/files?fileName=' + file}">
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" th:text="${file}"></li>
            </a>
</ul>
```

Expected:

> http://localhost:8080/files?fileName=!@#$%^&()_+=-{}[]'`~.doc

Actual:

> http://localhost:8080/files?fileName=!@#$%^&()_+=-{}[]'%60~.doc

And the weird thing is when I try to test the existence of `, I got following result.

> ${#strings.contains(file,'`')}  Result: True

> ${#strings.contains(file,'%60')} Result: False

How should I get the correct link to download the file?

Comment: What happens when you print out `fileName` in your `files` controller?  The encoding of URL variables should all be transparent, so why are you concerned that a link has been URL encoded?

Comment: The fileName is correct in my files controller. I concern it because I need to correct file name in my URL to download the file.

Comment: Any good server should interpret `%60` in the url as the backtick `  that's the whole point of url encoding.

Comment: [As you can see with this screenshot, where I am outputting the param `file`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WePiY.png)